# Error on smack 4.2.0 : IN AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack

i start openFire and test it with spark everything is ok but when i try to connect with smack 4.2.0 in android studio i got this error:

Ljavax/naming/directory/InitialDirContext;

and my dependencies is this:

> compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-bosh:4.2.0"

when remove this :
"compile org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.2.0"
from dependencies and add this:
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0"
my dependencies become like this:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0' compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.2.0" compile
>   "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-bosh:4.2.0"

I got This Error:

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The
>   following addresses failed: '192.168.209.2:5222' failed because:
>   de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for
>   192.168.209.2. IN A yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN, '192.168.209.2:5222' failed because:
>   de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for
>   192.168.209.2. IN AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN

the part of code that make error when i try to conn.connect() is this:

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = null;  
            try {  
                config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()  
                        .setUsernameAndPassword("admin", "thepass")  
                        .setXmppDomain("192.168.1.3")  
                        .setHost("192.168.209.2")  
                        .setPort(5222)  
                        .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)  
                        .build();  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
                AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);  
                conn1.setReplyTimeout(60000);  
                conn1.setPacketReplyTimeout(60000);  
                conn1.connect();
```

Comment: remove .setXmppDomain("192.168.1.3") this method and setServiceName() and provide user name and password while your login to the xmpp server

Comment: this works in smack 4.1.6 and I'm using currently it works for me thanks

Comment: yes its work in above 4.2.0 versions currently i'm using 4.1.9 and it's working but i need the new version 4.2.0

Comment: use .setHostAddress(InetAddress.getByName(DOMAIN_IP_ADDRESS)) instead of .setHost(HOST)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error you have encountered is stemming from incomplete addressing of your XMPP server.

Imagine this scenario:

> my ejabberd server is running on this address: 192.168.209.2 #ejabberd
>   server

There is a xmpp domain named "localhost" There are two JIDs,

> "davood@localhost" and "sadegh@localhost"

In smack, I want to authenticate with my user, say "davood@localhost". 
Then I do it as follow:

```
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.209.2");
            HostnameVerifier verifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            DomainBareJid serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("localhost");
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setHost(server) # it will be resolved by setHostAddress method
                    .setUsernameAndPassword("davood","mypass")
                    .setPort(5222)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                    .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
                    .setHostAddress(addr)
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                    .build();
            AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

            conn1.connect();

            if(conn1.isConnected()){
                Log.d("XMPP","Connected");
            }
            conn1.login();

            if(conn1.isAuthenticated()){
                Log.d("XMPP","Authenticated");
                EntityBareJid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("sadegh@localhost");
                org.jivesoftware.smack.chat2.Chat chat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn1).chatWith(jid);
                chat.send("Eureka, I am connected!");


            }
```

Comment: I have the same issue to connect emulator to ejabbred server. I followed your snippet code to set host address as 'InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2")'; but it throws this exception: The following addresses failed: 'null:5222'.

Comment: Iranian developers are always the best

Answer (score 9):

Please check :
https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.2-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

In previous versions of Smack, ConnectionConfiguration.setHost(String) could be used to set the XMPP service's host IP address. This is no longer possible due to the added DNSSEC support. You have to use the new connection configuration ConnectionConfiguration.setHostAddress(InetAddress) instead.

You can check this also.

[failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for xxxx. IN AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160061/failed-because-de-measite-minidns-hla-resolutionunsuccessfulexception-asking-f/43164006#43164006)

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat same issue with Xmpp Connection in Kotlin and I implemented the solution based on @davood-falahati 's answer with some changes, it worked fine for me:

```
private fun initializeXmppConnection(){
        val addr: InetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("90.182.109.19")
        val verifier: HostnameVerifier = HostnameVerifier { s, sslSession -> false }
        val serviceName: DomainBareJid = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("im.mydomain.ir")
        val config: XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setHost("90.182.109.19")
            .setUsernameAndPassword("60b9d4d75943a","9yqx7heu6aok4g40so8s0w8oocow8w8")
            .setPort(80)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
            .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
            .setHostAddress(addr)
            .setSendPresence(true)
            .setCompressionEnabled(false)
            .setConnectTimeout(30_000)
            .build()

        val conn: AbstractXMPPConnection = XMPPTCPConnection(config)
        conn.connect();

        if(conn.isConnected())
            Log.d("msn","Connected");

        conn.login();

        if(conn1.isAuthenticated()){
            Log.d("msn","Authenticated");

        }
    }
```