# failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for xxxx. IN AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

After I upgraded smack to 4.2.0 I am getting connection issue.

```
The following addresses failed: 'xxxx:5222' failed because: 

de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for xxxx.    IN  A yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN, '52.90.233.38:5222' failed because: de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for xxxx. IN  AAAA yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN
```

the issue happen when host is set in connection configuration builder.

example :

```
.setHost(ServiceConstants.CHAT_SERVER)
```

See https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.2-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

This is my final configuration, it worked after Davood Falahati help !

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ServiceConstants.CHAT_SERVER);
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setXmppDomain(JidCreate.from(ServiceConstants.CHAT_SERVER).asDomainBareJid())
                    .setPort(5222)
                    .setHostAddress(inetAddress)
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                    .setSendPresence(true)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on smack 4.2.0 : IN AAAA yielded an error response NX\_DOMAIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143359/error-on-smack-4-2-0-in-aaaa-yielded-an-error-response-nx-domain)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem mainly occurs in local networks when the xmpp server is not configured in local DNS. To solve the problem, explicitly address the xmpp server and use

`setHostAddress(InetAddress address)`

see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43163972/3741686)

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out

Comment: This resolved the issue, see https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.2-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide also