# Why cant I login to ejabberd through android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I cannot log in into my ejabberd server through my android emulator,though i can log in using pidgin.Below is my android code, its as minimal as possible and contains some deprecated API, its just for learning purposes(I don't think the deprecated API is part of the problem,but am no expert, am teachable). I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160061/failed-because-de-measite-minidns-hla-resolutionunsuccessfulexception-asking-f/43164006#43164006),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143359/error-on-smack-4-2-0-in-aaaa-yielded-an-error-response-nx-domain), and many [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160061/failed-because-de-measite-minidns-hla-resolutionunsuccessfulexception-asking-f) but there's no solution insight.

Android code

```
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 //import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;

 import org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManager;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManagerListener;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatMessageListener;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
 import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
 import org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException;
 import org.minidns.dnsserverlookup.android21.AndroidUsingLinkProperties;

 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     //InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

     public MainActivity() throws UnknownHostException {
     }

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         MyLoginTask task = new MyLoginTask();
         task.execute("");
     }


     private class MyLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             // Create a connection to the jabber.org server.
             XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = null;
             try {
            //try {

            //AndroidUsingLinkProperties.setup(getApplicationContext());
                     config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                              .setUsernameAndPassword("cray", "1234")
                            //.setServiceName()
                            //.setHost("192.168.0.104")
                             .setHost("10.0.2.2")
                             .setXmppDomain("localhost")
                           //.setHost("localhost")
                                 //.setHostAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"))
                        
 .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                            //.setServiceName("localhost")
                             .setPort(5280)
                           //.setDebuggerEnabled(true) // to view what's happening in detail
                        .build();
                 //} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                //    e.printStackTrace();
                //}
             } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                 //e.printStackTrace();
               Log.e("XMMP_APP", "Exception", e);
            }

             AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
             try {
                 conn1.connect();
                 if(conn1.isConnected())
                {
                     Log.w("app", "------connetion successful-------");
                 }
                 conn1.login();
                 if(conn1.isAuthenticated())
                 {
                     Log.w("app", "Auth done");
                     ChatManager chatManager =     ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn1);
                     chatManager.addChatListener(
                             new ChatManagerListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally)
                                {

                                    chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener()
                                    {
                                         @Override
                                         public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                                             System.out.println("Received message: "
                                                + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL"));

                                    }


                                });

                                Log.w("app", chat.toString());
                            }
                        });

                 }
             }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 //Log.w("app", e.toString());
                 Log.e("XMMP_APP", "Exception", e);
             }

             return "";
         }


         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
         }

    }
 }
```

I try to confirm if the user is logged in ejabberd server using **ejabberdctl connected_user_number** or simply **ejabberdctl connected_user** and i can see no user is logged in, though, i can comfortably log in with pidgin client.

This is the error am getting(Stack trace)

```
  08-23 11:57:10.981 2681-2681/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 08-23 11:57:11.002 2681-2687/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
 08-23 11:57:11.002 2681-2687/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-23 11:57:11.002 2681-2681/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.comcast.redfire-1/lib/x86
08-23 11:57:11.067 2681-2681/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter   androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-23 11:57:13.853 2681-2681/com.comcast.redfire I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
08-23 11:57:13.853 2681-2681/com.comcast.redfire I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
08-23 11:57:14.052 2681-2704/com.comcast.redfire D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-23 11:57:14.093 2681-2704/com.comcast.redfire I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-23 11:57:14.095 2681-2704/com.comcast.redfire W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-23 11:57:14.292 2681-2704/com.comcast.redfire D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb405abc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-23 11:57:14.307 2681-2704/com.comcast.redfire D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb405abc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaff49510)
08-23 11:57:14.424 2681-2704/com.comcast.redfire D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb405abc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaff49510)
08-23 11:57:30.872 2681-2703/com.comcast.redfire W/app: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '10.0.2.2:5222' failed because: org.minidns.util.MultipleIoException: null, failed to connect to /10.0.2.3 (port 53) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused), null, failed to connect to /8.8.8.8 (port 53) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable), sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable), failed to connect to /2001:4860:4860::8888 (port 53) after 5000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable), null, failed to connect to g.root-servers.net/192.112.36.4 (port 53) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable), sendto failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable), failed to connect to i.root-servers.net/2001:7fe::53 (port 53) after 5000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

- I added internet permission to my manifest file
- Changed http://localhost:5222 to http://127.0.0.1:5222 to http://10.0.2.2:5222 to http://127.0.0.1
  to even http://192.168.x.xxx:522 no success
- I even changed my gradle to add this line

  implementation 'de.measite.minidns:minidns-hla:0.2.4'

  no change:(
- i have invalidated cache and restarted the app many times.

Can someone help me solve this puzzle. Thank you for your time and attention.Sorry for poor formatting and incomplete info.

I think the problem is on 10.0.2.2. Since am using android emulator,I was recommended not to use 127.0.0.1, but use 10.0.2.2. As you can see,10.0.2.2 does not send back packets.How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have a working DNS setup. I would highly recommend you to install ejabberd on a server with proper networking setup and most importantly a domain + valid certificate.

Comment: You could be right, but how comes the pidgin client accesses the ejabberd server without any issues. Remember, am just testing on a localhost, not a live ip.But i will take your suggestion and try to come up with a solution.Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @vanitastae .I have edited the question and added some network configuration files and commands. I think the problem is on 10.0.2.2 which the emulator is supposed to use as opposed to 127.0.0.1.Can you help?

Comment: Pidgin is able to resolve localhost, as it is running on the same machine. You Android app however is running inside a virtualized Android, so localhost would point to the phone. Either read up on how to setup networking when using an Android emulator, or simply use an external server. I don't have experience with how to connect Android emulators to local servers, so I fear I cannot help you. For me using an external server with Smack works just fine without any problems.