# ResolutionUnsuccessfulException when trying to connect to XMPP server

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I have a [OpenFire](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) XMPP server running on my home machine and I'm trying to connect my Android app to it.

I'm in the same network, so I can reach the host (by ip). However, when I execute this:

```
try {
    val config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
        .setHost(ip)
        .setXmppDomain(domain)
        .build()
    val connection = XMPPTCPConnection(config)
    connection.connect().login()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this error:

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The
>   following addresses failed: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5222' failed because:
>   de.measite.minidns.hla.ResolutionUnsuccessfulException: Asking for
>   xxx.xxx.xx.xx.    IN  A yielded an error response NX_DOMAIN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on smack 4.2.0 : IN AAAA yielded an error response NX\_DOMAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143359/error-on-smack-4-2-0-in-aaaa-yielded-an-error-response-nx-domain)

Comment: This is a question about Smack (the client library), not about Openfire (the server implementation).